# Is $(\log n)^c = O(n)$ for any constant $c$?

Tags: asymptotics

Is $(\log n)^c = O(n)$ for any constant $c$?

For example, is $(\log n)^5 = O(n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\log^k n=o(n)$ for any constant $k$. Even stronger, for any $a,b>0$ two constants, we have $\log^a n=o(n^b)$.

Try showing using the limit definition of big O, and by repeatedly using L'Hospital's rule.

The big-O definition using limits: $f=O(g)$ if $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}}=c$ for some constant $c\ge 0$.

Comment: Your definition of big O using limits is wrong. You need to replace $\lim$ by $\lim\sup$.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I will change it, even though it doesn't really matter for this particular instance